# Graph database vertex/edge inference from a text (i.e. an informal Graph 'schema'), using Natural Language Processing (NLP) - does this exist?

Tags: graph, neo4j, nlp, titan, linguistics

Caveat Emptor - I'm neither a linguist nor a Graph theorist, however, I am a [Java] developer wishing to use a Graph database for persistence and the following topic is of interest to me, and I hope to others.

OK, the idea is to have some application or code to:

1. recognise the embedded relationship structures between named entities within a given piece of text
2. apply or expose these discovered relationships to usage within a Graph database structure.

In such a system, the text might essentially form a basic, layman-written graph schema of sorts. To better visualise this, here is some [very], basic text:

```
Andrew is married to Jane
```

Using the [online CLAWS parts-of-speech tagger (POS)](http://ucrel.lancs.ac.uk/claws/trial.html), I'm given the following:

```
Andrew_NP0 is_VBZ married_AJ0 to_SENT Jane_NP0
```

According to '[The BNC Basic (C5) Tagset](http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/docs/c5spec.html)' @ Oxford University, NP0='Proper noun', which is a name (as you know) but these NP0-tagged entries would lend themselves to becoming graph vertice instances/nodes (the end user could be further prompted to give these entries an encompassing 'type/description'). The verb(s), 'VBZ' and adjective(s), AJ0, might highlight graph relationships.

Once the end user has confirmed their graph representation, they might export it to [GraphML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GraphML), for re-import into a graph database such as [Titan](http://thinkaurelius.github.io/titan) or [Neo4j](http://www.neo4j.org).

So, the overall idea is to have a tool that allows a layman end user the ability to create Graph-theory-based database structures, using everyday language.

Does such a tool exist already?

Some of my observations above were influenced, in some way, by the following tools (amongst others):

http://www.plantuml.com <- UML diagrams defined using a simple and intuitive language
http://www.planttext.com <- See plantuml
http://www.acqualia.com/soulver <- An NLP-based calculator and currency exchange tool, using natural sentence phrases
http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml <- Stanford Log-linear Part-Of-Speech Tagger

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this exists in many different places.  Examples include [OpenCalais](http://www.opencalais.com/) (which was created by Reuters) and the [AlchemyAPI](http://www.alchemyapi.com/api/relation/entities.html).   There are a bunch of other toolkits and APIs like [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html) and [IBM's UIMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UIMA) that don't present you with a finished solution, but a bunch of tools necessary to build a bespoke solution.

This is a very deep area, subject to ongoing research.   I can't cover all of it here, but one thing to keep in mind is that solutions in this space are often highly specific to a certain "corpus" of documents.   Software which does any arbitrary English text well doesn't really exist.  Instead what you see is solutions that do it really well for business press releases.  Or intelligence reports.  Or newspaper articles.  Or medical alerts.   But not any, arbitrary text.

The area is also rife with a lot of problems; one of the big ones is known as "[Named Entity Recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition)"

`Andrew is married to Jane.   Andrew bought eggs yesterday`.

How many people are being discussed here?   Is the second Andrew the same as the first?  That's a very complicated and contextual question.  But you better get it right, otherwise you might have more or fewer "person" nodes in your resulting graph than you expect.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. I was aware of NLTK and OpenCalais (I've used the online viewer). Yes, your point regarding named entities is more than valid, however, my 'proposed' solution might attempt to get the end user to identify and associate extracted entities, so that they could be tracked across clauses (i.e. to create a dictionary of sorts from the input text). As I said, I'm not an expert, I just find the whole NLP idea very appealing (and thanks again).

Comment: Many such approaches have been built - they'd be categorized as "semi-automatic" text extraction.  You can search the literature; doubtful much that's reusable though, because when you go the semi-automated route, the nature of what you need out of the user gets **even more** domain specific.  The more domain specific, the less reusable.